# text going off the page in vue.js component

Tags: html, vue.js, bulma, buefy

I'm making a "reddit clone" and currently my text isn't wrapping, I'm not really sure why as when the title extends, it takes a new line, but not for `post.postMarkdown`. Here is my template.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-three-quarters">
        <p class="title">
          {{ post.postTitle }}
        </p>
        <p>
          <i>Posted by <a>{{ post.username }}</a></i>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-one-quarter right">
        <b-button type="is-primary" class="back" @click="backToSubforum">Back to {{ this.$store.state.subforum }}</b-button><br />
        <b-button type="is-primary" class="back" @click="backToForum">Back to forums</b-button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <p>{{ post.postMarkdown }}</p>
    
    <hr />
    <!--
      TODO: Comments
      -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is an example of a post where this happens
[image: no text wrap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `word-wrap: break-word`, this breaks unspaced words.

```css
/* just place on global p {} */
p.word-wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word
}

p.word-wrap-not {
  word-wrap: unset
}
```

```html
<p class="word-wrap">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>

<p class="word-wrap-not">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `p` containing the post content should have a max width:

```
 <p class="container is-max-desktop">{{ post.postMarkdown }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved any number of ways through css.  You could style your paragraphs (p tags), or add a css class to that specific paragraph for post content, as you have elsewhere, so

```
 <p class="post-content">{{ post.postMarkdown }}</p>
```

Set a width, text wrapping - or directly enter a style like

```
<p style="max-width:250px">{{ post.postMarkdown }}</p>
```

It would be helpful to see what css styles are in place, if any, in addition to your html, if this suggestion doesn't fix the issue.